# high voltage Buck-Boost converter

Tags: buck, boost, converter

I am looking for a Buck-Boost converter design that can take an input of 85 or 90 vrms to 265 Vrms. I would like the output to be in the range of 112-115V (DC) and current at least 150mA (dc). The overall power output at least 17Watts

Please Help I’ve been searching for a few days now and cannot find.
*Found a few by Fairchild however they will not work due to size of the transformer *

Comment: there is no transformer in buck boost converter.

Answer (score 3):

In general, this sort of "universal" AC-input power supply is going to be done as two separate stages: a boost converter (optionally including power factor correction) that creates a loosely-regulated 400VDC bus, and then a buck regulator that converts that to your output voltage, using a transformer to achieve isolation from the mains.

As an alternative, you might consider purchasing an off-the-shelf switching power supply rated at, say, 24V @ 1A (this would give you your isolation and most of your required certifications) and then use a relatively simple boost regulator to convert this to 112-115V @ 150 mA.